# What are lexeme, word and phrase in HPSG?

Tags: syntax, terminology, words, phrases, lexemes

In “Head-Driven Phrase Structure Grammar: The handbook” by Abeillé and Borsley, it says:

> lexeme, word, and phrase have a complex system of subtypes. The type lexical-sign, its subtypes, and the constraints on them are central to the lexicon of a language, while the type phrase, its subtypes, and the constraints on them are at the heart of the syntax.

I do not understand the distinction between sign, lexical-sign, phrase, lexeme and word in this framework. Is it that the word is the word itself, the lexeme is like the lemma (all possible grammatical forms contained or implied within), the phrase is like the grammatical category of the lexeme, i.e. identifying its functional role such as N and so on?

[image: Diagram]

How can lexeme and word be two sub-aspects of lexical-sign on the same level? If “phrase” means a syntactic composition of lexemes, why is that subsumed by the category “sign”? Wouldn’t you expect “sentence” or something there?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know the answer, as I'm not familiar with HPSG. But it seems to me that a phrase and a lexeme are fundamentally independent parts of the grammar, and _the phrase is like the grammatical category of the lexeme_ is incoherent. Surely a lexeme, (or rather, a representative of a lexeme) can be a component in a phrase, and might be the only component, but the phrse cannot be what specifies properties of the lexeme.

Comment: That paragraph itself isn't really about HPSG -- it's about linguistics. It says that the lexicon is organized in its own ways, and the grammar is organized in **its** own ways. Who could argue?

Comment: It sounds like the authors are getting ready to give their own definitions and are getting to the point where careful use of formatting, quotation marks, and typeface would be a big improvement. Something like _The type `Lexical-sign`, its subtypes, and the constraints on them are central to the lexicon of a language, while the type `Phrase`, its subtypes, and the constraints on them are at the heart of its syntax_.

Comment: As for the hierarchy, they appear to be telling you how they're going to be using the technical terms, which are not things one discovers like stingers on insects, but rather arbitrary terms of art, like _compound interest_. It's not like you can discover lexemes -- they come from analyses by linguists.

Comment: Whether I disagree or agree I find that somewhat beside the point, if interesting. I’m pretty sure these three ideas are different levels of basically the notion of “concepts” / “terms”. A word is a single unit, a lexeme is just a small multi-word phrase which cannot be broken into smaller pieces coherently, and a “sign” is just a lexeme with a bit of grammatical allowance, like “the daughter of my mother” for example.